# Allowing access to dev site via htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, prestashop-1.6

I have inherited a Prestashop website and the htaccess file is set up for all the required redirects. I want to allow access to the dev subdomain but the htaccess keeps redirecting to main site. I have tried to allow access with my limited knowledge and research from the web, but I get a 500 error when I upload the edited file.

the original rewrites are like so

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysitename.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]
RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysitename.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysitename.com$
RewriteRule ^.*$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
```

I have tried to add at the beginning after

> RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysitename.com$

these lines

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.mysitename.com$
RewriteRule ^/(.*)         http://dev.mysitename.com/index.php/$1 [L, QSA]
```

But I just keep getting a 500 error and can't experiment as it takes the site offline.

Comment: You need to **always** check your apache error logs when you get the 500 error. You can't just guess why it's broken. It will tell you what the issue is then you can fix it..

Comment: its not broken, I just removed the lines I tried to add, I got the lines from another stack overflow question and changed the relevant details to match mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your new lines are going between an existing RewriteCond and RewriteRule pair and breaking their syntax.  Try moving your lines above the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.mysitename.com$` line.

Answer (score 0):

Have it this way:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_env.c>
SetEnv HTTP_MOD_REWRITE On
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysitename\.com$
RewriteRule . - [E=REWRITEBASE:/]

RewriteRule ^api/?(.*)$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}webservice/dispatcher.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]

# Dispatcher
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysitename\.com$
RewriteRule !(?:^|/)index\.php$ %{ENV:REWRITEBASE}index.php [NC,L]
</IfModule>

#If rewrite mod isn't enabled
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?controller=404
```